# Reflection - EasyMock - ClassCastException

Tags: java, reflection, junit, easymock

I have a JUnit Test with EasyMock.  I'm trying to use reflection to pass the request to a private method.  How do I do this.  The following is my source & output:

```
@Test
public void testGoToReturnScreen(){
    HttpServletRequest request = createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);

    expect(request.getParameter("firstName")).andReturn("o");
    expect(request.getAttribute("lastName")).andReturn("g");

    request.setAttribute("lastName", "g");   
    replay(request);

    CAction cAction = new CAction();
    System.out.println("BEFORE");
    try {
        System.out.println("[1]: "+request);
        System.out.println("[2]: "+request.getClass());
        System.out.println("[3]: test1 direct call: "+cAction.test1(request));
        System.out.println("[4]: test1:"+(String) genericInvokMethod(cAction, "test1", new Object[]{HttpServletRequest.class}, new Object[]{request}));
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("e: "+e);
    }
    System.out.println("AFTER");
}

public static Object genericInvokMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] formalParams, Object[] actualParams) {
    Method method;
    Object requiredObj = null;

    try {
        method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, (Class<?>[]) formalParams);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        requiredObj = method.invoke(obj, actualParams);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return requiredObj;
}
```

The Struts Action is simply:

```
    private String test1(HttpServletRequest r){

    return "test1";
}
```

In the System.out.println commands above I get the following output:

```
BEFORE
[1]: EasyMock for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
[2]: class $Proxy5
[3]: test1 direct call: test1
e: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Class;
AFTER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, (Class<?>[]) formalParams);
```

you are casting an `Object[]` to a `Class[]`. This won't work. Those types are not compatible.

Instead, change your `formalParams` parameter to be of type `Class[]` .

```
public static Object genericInvokMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Class[] formalParams, Object[] actualParams) {
```

and call it

```
genericInvokMethod(cAction, "test1", new Class[]{HttpServletRequest.class}, new Object[]{request})
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much for setting me straight.  You Rock!